# errno 2 deploy django app inheroku

Tags: heroku

hello i'm trying tu push a django app with heroku but there is an error let me show you my log

```
Décompte des objets: 931, fait.
Compression des objets: 100% (889/889), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (931/931), 5.10 MiB | 602.00 KiB/s, fait.
Total 931 (delta 79), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python/Django app detected
remote: -----> Preparing virtualenv version 1.7
remote:  !     Virtualenv corrupt, rebuilding.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks    /b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/src/virtualenv-1.7/virtualenv.py", line 2098, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/src/virtualenv-       1.7/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
remote:     never_download=options.never_download)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/src/virtualenv-1.7/virtualenv.py", line 1042, in create_environment
remote:     install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/src/virtualenv-1.7/virtualenv.py", line 640, in install_pip
remote:     filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/src/virtualenv-1.7/virtualenv.py", line 966, in call_subprocess
remote:     cwd=cwd, env=env)
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
remote:     errread, errwrite)
remote:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
remote:     raise child_exception
remote: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
remote:        New python executable in ./bin/python
remote:        Installing distribute.................................done.
remote:        Installing pip...
remote:          Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command /tmp/build_799f2de31...5ae/bin/easy_install /app/tmp/buildpacks/...ort/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz
remote:        ...Installing pip...done.
remote: -----> Activating virtualenv
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b63c5dfcdb62db9ec6d96d0df277375e215c0a98586cc154dc2ae23edea8caeeaef96ba8ccdbdf02b5e12a89555559bff4f076afa72c36df6d52ac7c19b73605/bin/compile: line 82: bin/activate: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python/Django app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to echecetmat.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/echecetmat.git
```

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: impossible de pousser des références vers 'https://git.heroku.com/echecetmat.git'

Comment: please format the log, they are virtually impossible to read as is.

Comment: it is done please help me